# Can't delete trash files on USB stick

Tags: networking, usb, 64-bit, hardware, 14.10

I'm having trouble deleting files that magically appeared on my USB stick.

The folder was a trash folder which I have never seen before which also contains files that are in my trash as well.

I keep getting an error on both my flash drive and my trash.
I'm new to Ubuntu so I'll need careful explanations.

Answer (score 7):

The Ubuntu GUI file manager called `nautilus` usually creates a `.Trash` folder in each drive you insert to your system. Every time you delete a file in `nautilus` it is copied in the `.Trash` folder. Then you are allowed to recover or permanently delete the file.

On the other hand, when you use the terminal no `.Trash` folder is used. So, you can delete this floder using the terminal. Open a terminal and type

```
$ rm -rf /media/username/diskname/.Trash
```

Comment: **Newbie alert!**  Please edit your answer, as http://askubuntu.com/users/354812/xxxneedlesxxx is bound to just copy-paste your answer into that black magic thing a.k.a. "the terminal"  ;-)

Comment: @Fabby I edited the response. Did you had something like this in mind?

Comment: This commands fails with the error: "Read only file system" on Ubuntu 14.04.